# Order of operation in .htaccess file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to give an access to file1.php and file2.php from everyone (0.0.0.0/0) and give an access to all other files in a particular directory from only 192.168.1.0/24 subnet. I have tried following config, which did not work:

```
<Files ".htaccess">
  deny from all
</Files>

<Files "file1.php">
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Files>

<Files "file2.php">
  order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch ".*">
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 192.168.1.
</FilesMatch>
```

Result: Files file1.php and file2.php are opening only from 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you put the `.*` rule first? My guess is that all rules are evaluated in order, and that the last rule overwrites the result of the first rules.

This is definitely documented in the Apache Web Server documentation, which you should read. It's well-written with many examples.